# Finding PPAs for package names

Tags: debian

Frequently I'm looking for PPAs for various software (instead of downloading .deb package), both because it's easier to update as well as easier to add to Ansible. Usually, I find it sooner or later using random Google searching, but it's not a reliable process.

For example, I'm unable to find PPAs for:

1. signal (text communicator)
2. balena etcher (software for burning ISOs on USBs)
3. snapd (snap is an alternative package manager)

How can I make sure, that I will find PPAs for given software? I frequently know what's the package name. Is there any website or bash command that will allow me to get PPA for given package name?

Comment: a PPA is just an arbitrary unsupported third-party package repository. what's wrong with the packages already available in the default repository where they exist, such as snapd?

Comment: my linux mint when I'm trying to install snap says: E: Package 'snapd' has no installation candidate @Fox

Comment: @spam Mint blocks `snapd` installations, you need to remove `/etc/apt/preferences.d/nosnap.pref` or something like that. The `snapd` package itself is available in the Ubuntu repositories which Mint uses by default.